# Threading error in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I created this program to find some prime numbers which runs the same function 2 times with different input.but when i run it i get an error 
"prime() argument after * must be an iterable, not int"

[python source code file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln2UN.png)

the error message says 
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOtVi.png)

Comment: please post the code here (properly indented) and do not link to an *image* of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `args = [10]` instead; args is supposed to be a list of arguments.